# Xgboost OneHotEncoding: merge numerical and encoded array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, xgboost, one-hot-encoding

My dataset contains one numerical feature and one categorical feature. It only has 20 observations (for the question purpose).

X is a numpy array of shape (20,1) and is like:

```
array([[10],  
   [465],  
   [3556],  
   [899],  
   [090], 
   ....]]
```

encoded_x is a numpy array of shape (20,4) and is like:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       ...................]]
```

**Question:** Now, how can I merge those array to give them as input to Xgboost?
How should the final array look like?
My understanding is that numerical features should not be encoded, that is why I have two distinct arrays.

Comment: You can use [numpy hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) if those two arrays have same rows (which they probably should).

Answer (score 2):

XGBoost approach is a bit different from, say, neural networks. It requires you to have one numerical matrix for the input, and this makes you think differently about *what a feature is*.

From your point of view, there are *2 features*: one categorical and one numerical. But XGBoost sees *5 features*, 4 of which, for some reason, take just two values: `0` or `1`. XGBoost doesn't know about one-hot encoding, it sees only numbers.

As a result, no matter how you encode your categorical feature (ordinal or one-hot), you should just concatenate all of result arrays into a single 2D array and fit it to the model.

```
x1 = np.arange(20).reshape([-1, 1])        # numerical feature
x2 = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=[20, 4]) # not one-hot, but still ok for XGBoost
x = np.concatenate([x1, x2], axis=1)       # now it's 5 XGBoost features
```